# jquery wrap content between elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some content separated by `<hr>` markers. What I need to do is wrap everthing between the beginning maker and the ending marker.

Given this markup:

```
<hr class=begin>
 some content
 <some tags>
 more content
 <more tags>
<hr class=end>
```

This is what I need it to be:

```
<hr class=begin>
 <div class=content>
   some content
   <some tags>
   more content
   <more tags>
 </div>
<hr class=end>
```

I can do this with `.nextAll()` but it seems like there should be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) like this:

```
$("hr.begin").nextUntil("hr.end").wrapAll("<div class='content'></div>");
```

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, as nextUntil() is the correct alternative to nextAll(), but neither method will not work for what I want to do because I also need to wrap free text that is between the markers. I'm going to re-ask the question with this specific. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) method of jQuery.

> Get all following siblings of each
>   element up to but not including the
>   element matched by the selector.