# Wrap content between 2 divs in the first div, delete second

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to create sections in a Caldera Form for Wordpress in order to group certain sets of fields for styling purposes.

I can add html fields in Caldera and as such I can create markup as such ;

```
<div class="section begin"></div>
```

Thereafter follow my selected fields, let's say;

```
<div class="field"></div>
<div class="field"></div>
<div class="field"></div>
<div class="field"></div>
```

The I can add a further html element as such;

```
<div class="section end"></div>
```

I need to 'wrap' the fields in the first div and delete the second, resulting in;

```
<div class="section begin">
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
</div>
```

Can this be done with jQuery? I followed this thread [jquery wrap content between elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272039/jquery-wrap-content-between-elements) but it doesnt quite do what I need.

All help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by moving each `.field` into the `.begin` element using this scriptlet:

```
$('.field').each(function() {
    $(this).append('.begin');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alvin. What if the pattern is repeated multiple times across the form? In other words I may have 5 or 6 'instances' of the .begin element.

Comment: hmm..not working for me. I already have some jQuery running on the form so it may be related to that. Not sure what to try next.

Comment: Well, to help you with that, you need to show me how the HTML looks like with more instances to see how and where the sections are and where the fields